# I keep getting the error System.IO.FileNotFoundException when trying to play a sound in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to play a sound using the Plugin.Maui.Audio package.

```
AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("done.wav")).Play();
```

But it keeps giving me the error "file not found". The Audio File is in my Resources/Raw Directory with the build action MauiAsset.
(I am migrating from xamarin to .NET MAUI)

The only time it worked was when I used "Resources/Raw/done.wav" and ran it on windows instead of the android emulator.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the error message actually says? Please post the actual error message (as text) and show relevant parts of your *.csproj* file and code. Including a screenshot of the file location in the Project Explorer might also help. Generally, the single line of code looks fine, but more context would be useful. IIRC, the call must be made on the MainThread, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My .csproj missed the line

```
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
```