# accessing resources (sound file) in .Net Maui library

Tags: maui

I have this working in a .Net Maui Application in iOS.  However, I moved logic over into a library.  I can see how this may not work, but I haven't found anything stating it wouldn't.

One of the things I wanted to move over to the library was the sound playing to notify the user when the backend was processing.

I had to create the Resources\Raw folders in the library project.  Within the Raw folder, I placed the audio files and set their build to mauiasset.

This line:

```
 private IAudioPlayer playerStartSound;

public TestApp()
{
   playerStartSound = audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(@"record-start.mp3"));
}
```

Gives an exception:

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0A65184E-4609-3ED6-BT79-2F1B3CC77D1E/TestApp.app/record-start.mp3
```

I've also tried to specify the folder:

```
 playerStartSound = audioManager.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(@"\Resources\Raw\record-start.mp3"));
```

Which gives the exact same error.

Does anyone know what is going on here and how I can access these files (if it's going to work)?

Update, I found this: [I keep getting the error System.IO.FileNotFoundException when trying to play a sound in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920940/i-keep-getting-the-error-system-io-filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-play-a-s?rq=2)

which changed the error to this (on the same line):

```
ex = {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at SpeechLib.SpeechHandler.LoadSounds() in D:\Dev\TestApp\SpeechLib\SpeechHandler.cs:line 57}

No inner exception.

This is a .Net 8 Library, not specifically a .Net Maui related item.  So it's probable that I'm encountering something related to this.

This is my project file now:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\Raw\bing.wav" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Raw\record-end.mp3" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Raw\record-start.mp3" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Raw\tic.wav" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Raw\unknown.wav" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\bing.wav" />
  <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\record-end.mp3" />
  <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\record-start.mp3" />
  <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\tic.wav" />
  <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\unknown.wav" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Could you please post the full log about this problem?

Comment: The part where you say it gives this exception, there is no exception just a file path. Could you please share more details on the error you're seeing and maybe full blocks of (relevant) code rather than just lines?

Comment: This would be the only relevant line of code.  It's on the instantiation of the class.  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920940/i-keep-getting-the-error-system-io-filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-play-a-s?rq=2 which did change the error, it's now a null reference.  I'll update my question.  Problem is, the app shuts down quickly because it's not started.  It seems to be an odd effect of Maui when you try to step debug through startup and you're not fast enough, it shuts the app down.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: Create a class library, in the class put in the TestApp() method, add in a wav (and create the Resources\Raw) folder.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on the specific steps?